# Bash Script - sed command for color

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a log file and I would like to highlight some key words when it display the output.

So I like the word, **myaccount** and **myfile.txt** to be a different color so it stands out.  This is what I have

```
blue='\e[0;34m'
end='\033[0m'

user="myaccount"
less someapp.log | sed "s/\${blue}/$user/${end}/" | grep --color=auto myfile.xml
```

This should be my output:
Jan:01:2023 03:35:26:491 /blah1/blah2/**myaccount**/blah3/**myfile.txt**

but this is the error message I get,

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command
```

How would I go about to set the 2 characters in a string to have a different color?

Comment: Try using single quotes instead like this: `'s/\${blue}/$user/${end}/'`.

Comment: Try using the `tput` [command](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php) instead of specifying ANSI escape sequences by hand.  This will not only make you script less ugly but will a) strip them entirely on terminals that don't support color b) provide alternate sequences when required.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, is OP use single quotes the variables will not be interpreted

Comment: So I tried single and double quotes or just ran this command,   less someapp.log | sed "s/\${blue}/$user/${end}/" it gave me the same error message.  It seems the issue is with the sed command

Comment: also tried tput but same error message

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: 
https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/134824-using-sed-change-specific-words-color.html

This is what they have:

```
cat $file | sed ''/$word/s//`printf "\033[32m$word\033[0m"`/''
```

So I tailored it to my command and this is the final result:

```
less someapp.log | sed ''/$user/s//`printf "${blue}$user${end}"`/'' | grep --color=auto myfile.xml
```

Now, the two words, will be display in a different color.